# Starting npm run start over https instead of http

Tags: npm, https

I am trying to run iiif-manifest-store over https instead of http. By default it runs in http. Is there a way I can fix this? I am using: 
    npm run start command
to start off the server on port 3001

https://github.com/textandbytes/iiif-manifest-store

Comment: Set HTTPS=true before you run the start command.

Comment: tried it but did not work unfortunately

Comment: Do you have a package.json file

Comment: yes I do. Tried to change "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }, to "scripts": {
    "start": "HTTPS=true node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }, but still did not work

Comment: "scripts": { "start": "set HTTPS=true&& npm start"} this should work

Comment: should i add that to "start": "node server.js" to become "start": "node server.js set HTTPS=true&& npm start"

Comment: Yes you need to change that to what I mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200578/discussion-between-sachin-yadav-and-hannah).

Comment: Unfortunately no luck :(

Comment: You can also create a file called .env in the root of your project, then write
HTTPS=true
After that, just run "npm start" as you usually do to start your app.

Comment: Did this one work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no luck here as well

Comment: Let me know this you want your local host to run in https on your Chrome Web browser is it so ???

Comment: Yes but not a localhost...it is a remote server

Comment: @SachinYadav by setting HTTPS=true in env file works for me. Thanks